# Calling PostgreSQL stored procedure in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, plpgsql, cakephp-3.0

I am working on my new project in CakePHP 3 with PostgreSQL database. I have created a few stored procedures. I am trying to call them in cakePHP 3.0 using below code. But not sure, Is this the right way to do this.

```
$sql = "SELECT check_pass('test123','123456')";
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$results = $connection->execute($sql)->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Please suggest if is any other better way to do this.

Comment: Are you facing any problem with this?

Comment: no its working but i just want to know is it a correct way of calling stored procedure or not?

Comment: If your function returns a single value the way you've done it is ok. In some cases it's recommended to use `select * from my_function(args)`, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014219/select-function-in-postgresql-makes-too-much-calls-to-function/31014400#31014400).

Comment: in what class is the code in the question?

Comment: its in the controller.